# Enter automatically generated email in text area with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have this code, what it does is generate a random email with a list of names.

But, not how to do so that when chrome opens, enter the generated email in the email section.

this is the code

```
rom selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from config import keys
import threading
import time
import random
import string
import nameslist

"NAMES"
"From https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/roche/courses/s15si335/proj1/files.php%3Ff=names.txt.html"

e_address_count = 1

email_providers = ["yahoo","gmail","hotmail","outlook"]
tlds = [".com",".es"] # You can add more domains

for i in range(e_address_count):
        #random_numbers = random.randint(1,9999)
        random_server_sel = "@"+random.choice(email_providers)+random.choice(tlds)
        randnames = random.choice(nameslist.Names)
        random_4lettercomb = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for l in range(2))
        email = print(randnames+random_4lettercomb+random_server_sel)

time.sleep(0.5)

def timeme(method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        startTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        endTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        print((endTime - startTime)/1000, 's')
        return result
    return wrapper

# will cookies improve load time?
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.fallablasgamez.com/votaci%C3%B3n-premi-flama")


@timeme
def order():
#intruducir email
    time.sleep(0.3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input_comp-lgb8swdu"]').send_keys(email)
#intruducir numero falla Mayor
    time.sleep(0.2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input_comp-lgb8qa87"]').send_keys(keys['numeromañor'])
#Introducir falla Menor
    time.sleep(0.2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-form"]/div[5]/div/div/input').send_keys(keys['numeromenor'])
#Botton Capcha

#Botton Enviar
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/section[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/form/div/div/div[6]/button/span').click()

if __name__ == '__main__':


    # get product url
    driver.get(keys['product_url'])
    order()
```

Copy the generated email and insert it where it says email
This prints the code of the email generated

```
email = print(randnames+random_4lettercomb+random_server_sel)
```

I enter it in this area so that it can be attached

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input_comp-lgb8swdu"]').send_keys(email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot be reproduced out of the box because the required `config` and `namelist` modules are missing. It is worth noting though, that using `print` does not return any value that can be stored in a variable. Therefore, if you use `print` to create a value and try to store it in a variable using an assignment statement, the variable will be assigned the value `None`.

If you want to assign the concatenated string to the `email` variable, you can use string concatenation like this:

```py
email = randnames + random_4lettercomb + random_server_sel
```